# Failed to link OpenSSL using MinGW/Cmake (TLS_method,`SSL_CTX_ctrl', .etc..)

Tags: windows, cmake, openssl, mingw, static-linking

I'm going crazy to link OpenSSL with project that I'm implementing using MinGW and setting the project with CMake Gui.
It basically fails to link properly with the OpenSSL libraries. 
Here's my CMake settings -> https://ibb.co/5Y0TB5Y.

Here there are the `CMakeLists.txt` that I used in my project:
 1. Main `CMakeLists.txt`

```
`cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (MyPluginDesignProject)

SET (BOOST_ROOT "C:\\Program Files\\boost_1_68_0")
SET (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "C:\\Program Files\\boost_1_68_0\\include")
SET (BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "C:\\Program Files\\boost\\lib")

SET (BOOST_MIN_VERSION "1.68.0")
set (Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost ${BOOST_MIN_VERSION} REQUIRED)
if (NOT Boost_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Fatal error: Boost (version >= 1.55) required.")
else()
  message(STATUS "Setting up BOOST")
  message(STATUS " Includes - ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  message(STATUS " Library  - ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
  SET (Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:\\Program Files\\boost\\lib")

  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
endif (NOT Boost_FOUND)

message("Binary path " ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
message("Source path " ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
#define the path relative the headers 
set (PLUGIN_INCLUDES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Headers)

#telle the compiler to check the headers in the  PLUGIN_INCLUDES path for the project's headers 
include_directories(${PLUGIN_INCLUDES})

add_subdirectory(Plugins\\MyPlugin)

#define the variable PROJECT_SOURCE that includes all the cpp within the "Headers" folder
set(PROJECT_INCLUDES Headers/GameInstance.h)

#define the variable PROJECT_SOURCE that includes all the cpp within the "Source" folder
set(PROJECT_SOURCE
Source/main.cpp
Source/GameInstance.cpp
)
add_executable(MyPluginDesignProject ${PROJECT_SOURCE})

#Links the library to the program : 
# keyword: PRIVATE 
target_link_libraries (MyPluginDesignProject PRIVATE MyPlugin)`
```

2 Plugin `CMakeLists.txt`

```
`cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

add_subdirectory(ThirdParty\\Simple-Web-Server)

file(GLOB
    MYPLUGIN_SERVER_PLUGIN_HEADERS Headers/*.h
    )

file(GLOB
    MYPLUGIN_SERVER_PLUGIN_SOURCES Source/*.cpp
    )

file(GLOB
    SIMPLE_WEB_SERVER ThirdParty/Simple-Web-Server/*.hpp
    )   

    add_library(
        MyPlugin #name of the library
        STATIC #STATIC library . other option: SHARED - MODULE. STATIC is  default
        ${MYPLUGIN_SERVER_PLUGIN_HEADERS}
        ${MYPLUGIN_SERVER_PLUGIN_SOURCES}
        ${SIMPLE_WEB_SERVER}
        )

    find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
    if (OPENSSL_FOUND)
        include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
        target_link_libraries(MyPlugin PUBLIC ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})

    endif()

#definition  of the include path of the library that will be usedd for linking 
#keyword: the "PUBLIC" keyword means that abyone who's including this library, will include also all the 
#includes included in this library. 
#if the keyword is "PRIVATE" then the program that includes this library won't automatically include its libraries
target_include_directories(MyPlugin PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Headers)
target_include_directories(MyPlugin PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/Simple-Web-Server)

target_link_libraries(MyPlugin PUBLIC ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries (MyPlugin PUBLIC simple-web-server)


target_compile_definitions(MyPlugin PUBLIC MYPLUGIN_SERVER_PLUGIN_VERSION=1.2.0)`
```

3. SimpleWebServer `CMakeLists.txt` (included in the plugin `CMakeLists.txt`)

`
    cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)

```
project (Simple-Web-Server)

option(USE_STANDALONE_ASIO "set ON to use standalone Asio instead of Boost.Asio" OFF)
option(BUILD_TESTING "set ON to build library tests" OFF)

if(NOT MSVC)
    add_compile_options(-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wsign-conversion)
else()
    add_compile_options(/W1)
endif()

add_library(simple-web-server INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(simple-web-server INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(simple-web-server INTERFACE ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})

# TODO 2020 when Debian Jessie LTS ends:
# Remove Boost system, thread, regex components; use Boost::<component> aliases; remove Boost target_include_directories
if(USE_STANDALONE_ASIO)
    target_compile_definitions(simple-web-server INTERFACE USE_STANDALONE_ASIO)
    include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
    CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX(asio.hpp HAVE_ASIO)
    if(NOT HAVE_ASIO)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Standalone Asio not found")
    endif()
else()
    find_package(Boost 1.53.0 COMPONENTS system thread REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(simple-web-server INTERFACE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    target_include_directories(simple-web-server INTERFACE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU" AND CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 4.9)
        target_compile_definitions(simple-web-server INTERFACE USE_BOOST_REGEX)
        find_package(Boost 1.53.0 COMPONENTS regex REQUIRED)
        target_link_libraries(simple-web-server INTERFACE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
        target_include_directories(simple-web-server INTERFACE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    endif()
endif()
if(WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(simple-web-server INTERFACE ws2_32 wsock32)
endif()

if(APPLE)
    set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR "/usr/local/opt/openssl")
endif()
find_package(OpenSSL)
if(OPENSSL_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Using OpenSSL ${OPENSSL_VERSION}")
    include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_compile_definitions(simple-web-server INTERFACE HAVE_OPENSSL)
    message ("OpenSSL library is " ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
    target_link_libraries(simple-web-server INTERFACE ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
    target_link_libraries(simple-web-server INTERFACE OpenSSL::SSL)

    target_include_directories(simple-web-server INTERFACE ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

# If Simple-Web-Server is not a sub-project:
if("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
    add_executable(http_examples http_examples.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(http_examples simple-web-server)
    find_package(Boost 1.53.0 COMPONENTS system thread filesystem REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(http_examples ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    target_include_directories(http_examples PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    if(OPENSSL_FOUND)
        add_executable(https_examples https_examples.cpp)
        target_link_libraries(https_examples simple-web-server)
        target_link_libraries(https_examples ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
        target_include_directories(https_examples PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    endif()

    set(BUILD_TESTING ON)

    install(FILES server_http.hpp client_http.hpp server_https.hpp client_https.hpp crypto.hpp utility.hpp status_code.hpp DESTINATION include/simple-web-server)
endif()

if(BUILD_TESTING)
    enable_testing()
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()`
```

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've tried to use both the openssl `*.a` and the `*.lib` libraries and I had the same result. My OpenSSL version is 1.1.0k and Boost is 1.68.
I also tried to set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS = -lssl -lcrypto` but the output says that `ld.exe` can't find the libraries. Any help?

Output:

```
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\MyProjectDesignProject.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
    "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\MyProjectDesignProject.dir/objects.a
    C:\MinGw\mingw32\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\MyProjectDesignProject.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\MyProjectDesignProject.dir\objects1.rsp
    C:\MinGw\mingw32\bin\g++.exe    -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\MyProjectDesignProject.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o MyProjectDesignProject.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libMyProjectDesignProject.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\MyProjectDesignProject.dir\linklibs.rsp
    CMakeFiles\MyProjectDesignProject.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail17openssl_init_base7do_initD1Ev[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail17openssl_init_base7do_initD1Ev]+0x11): undefined reference to `CONF_modules_unload'
    CMakeFiles\MyProjectDesignProject.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost4asio5error6detail12ssl_category7messageB5cxx11Ei[__ZNK5boost4asio5error6detail12ssl_category7messageB5cxx11Ei]+0x11): undefined reference to `ERR_reason_error_string'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text+0x1da): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE]+0x2b): undefined reference to `ERR_clear_error'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE]+0x79): undefined reference to `TLS_method'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE]+0x81): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE]+0xba): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_ctrl'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE]+0xdf): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_ctrl'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE]+0xe9): undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE]+0xf1): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE]+0x159): undefined reference to `TLS_server_method'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE]+0x161): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE]+0x1c9): undefined reference to `TLS_method'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE]+0x239): undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE]+0x2a9): undefined reference to `TLS_server_method'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextC1ENS1_12context_base6methodE]+0x72e): undefined reference to `ERR_get_error'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextD1Ev[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextD1Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_get_default_passwd_cb_userdata'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextD1Ev[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextD1Ev]+0x5a): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextD1Ev[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextD1Ev]+0x6f): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_get_ex_data'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextD1Ev[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextD1Ev]+0x8d): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_get_ex_data'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextD1Ev[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextD1Ev]+0xc4): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_ex_data'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextD1Ev[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7contextD1Ev]+0xd1): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_free'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context11set_optionsElRNS_6system10error_codeE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context11set_optionsElRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x19): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context15set_verify_modeEiRNS_6system10error_codeE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context15set_verify_modeEiRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x12): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_get_verify_callback'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context15set_verify_modeEiRNS_6system10error_codeE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context15set_verify_modeEiRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x2c): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_verify'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context16load_verify_fileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERNS_6system10error_codeE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context16load_verify_fileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0xb): undefined reference to `ERR_clear_error'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context16load_verify_fileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERNS_6system10error_codeE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context16load_verify_fileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x2e): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context16load_verify_fileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERNS_6system10error_codeE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context16load_verify_fileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x44): undefined reference to `ERR_get_error'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context24set_default_verify_pathsERNS_6system10error_codeE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context24set_default_verify_pathsERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x18): undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context24set_default_verify_pathsERNS_6system10error_codeE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context24set_default_verify_pathsERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x2e): undefined reference to `ERR_get_error'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context26use_certificate_chain_fileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERNS_6system10error_codeE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl7context26use_certificate_chain_fileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0xb): undefined reference to `ERR_clear_error'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost4asio3ssl20rfc2818_verificationclEbRNS1_14verify_contextE[__ZNK5boost4asio3ssl20rfc2818_verificationclEbRNS1_14verify_contextE]+0x38e): undefined reference to `X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineC1EP10ssl_ctx_st[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineC1EP10ssl_ctx_st]+0x11): undefined reference to `SSL_new'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineC1EP10ssl_ctx_st[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineC1EP10ssl_ctx_st]+0x2d): undefined reference to `ERR_get_error'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineC1EP10ssl_ctx_st[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineC1EP10ssl_ctx_st]+0x7b): undefined reference to `SSL_ctrl'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineC1EP10ssl_ctx_st[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineC1EP10ssl_ctx_st]+0xa0): undefined reference to `SSL_ctrl'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineC1EP10ssl_ctx_st[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineC1EP10ssl_ctx_st]+0xc5): undefined reference to `SSL_ctrl'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineC1EP10ssl_ctx_st[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineC1EP10ssl_ctx_st]+0xf1): undefined reference to `BIO_new_bio_pair'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineD1Ev[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineD1Ev]+0x38): undefined reference to `SSL_get_ex_data'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineD1Ev[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineD1Ev]+0x64): undefined reference to `SSL_set_ex_data'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineD1Ev[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineD1Ev]+0x72): undefined reference to `BIO_free'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineD1Ev[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engineD1Ev]+0x7f): undefined reference to `SSL_free'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine10get_outputERKNS0_14mutable_bufferE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine10get_outputERKNS0_14mutable_bufferE]+0x30): undefined reference to `BIO_read'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine9put_inputERKNS0_12const_bufferE[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine9put_inputERKNS0_12const_bufferE]+0x30): undefined reference to `BIO_write'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine14map_error_codeERNS_6system10error_codeE[__ZNK5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine14map_error_codeERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x62): undefined reference to `BIO_ctrl'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine14map_error_codeERNS_6system10error_codeE[__ZNK5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine14map_error_codeERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x8f): undefined reference to `SSL_get_shutdown'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine7performEMS3_FiPvjES4_jRNS_6system10error_codeEPj[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine7performEMS3_FiPvjES4_jRNS_6system10error_codeEPj]+0x13): undefined reference to `BIO_ctrl_pending'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine7performEMS3_FiPvjES4_jRNS_6system10error_codeEPj[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine7performEMS3_FiPvjES4_jRNS_6system10error_codeEPj]+0x1b): undefined reference to `ERR_clear_error'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine7performEMS3_FiPvjES4_jRNS_6system10error_codeEPj[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine7performEMS3_FiPvjES4_jRNS_6system10error_codeEPj]+0x74): undefined reference to `SSL_get_error'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine7performEMS3_FiPvjES4_jRNS_6system10error_codeEPj[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine7performEMS3_FiPvjES4_jRNS_6system10error_codeEPj]+0x8d): undefined reference to `BIO_ctrl_pending'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine9do_acceptEPvj[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine9do_acceptEPvj]+0x12): undefined reference to `SSL_accept'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine10do_connectEPvj[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine10do_connectEPvj]+0x12): undefined reference to `SSL_connect'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine7do_readEPvj[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine7do_readEPvj]+0x30): undefined reference to `SSL_read'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine8do_writeEPvj[__ZN5boost4asio3ssl6detail6engine8do_writeEPvj]+0x30): undefined reference to `SSL_write'
    Plugins/MyProject/libMyProject.a(MyProjectMatch.cpp.obj):MyProjectMatch.cpp:(.text$_ZN9SimpleWeb6ClientIN5boost4asio3ssl6streamINS2_19basic_stream_socketINS2_2ip3tcpEEEEEE9handshakeERKSt10shared_ptrINS_10ClientBaseIS9_E7SessionEE[__ZN9SimpleWeb6ClientIN5boost4asio3ssl6streamINS2_19basic_stream_socketINS2_2ip3tcpEEEEEE9handshakeERKSt10shared_ptrINS_10ClientBaseIS9_E7SessionEE]+0x51): undefined reference to `SSL_ctrl'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\MyProjectDesignProject.dir\build.make:115: MyProjectDesignProject.exe] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/MyProject_Repos/Cpp_Plugin_Repo/cpp-plugin-repo/server-cpp/Build'
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:80: CMakeFiles/MyProjectDesignProject.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/MyProject_Repos/Cpp_Plugin_Repo/cpp-plugin-repo/server-cpp/Build'
    make: *** [Makefile:86: all] Error 2
```

Comment: You forgot to add to the question the **code** (`CMakeLists.txt`) of your project. Note, that on Stack Overflow we prefer a code in some *minimal* form ([mcve]).

Comment: ehi @Tsyvarev, thanks for the comment and sorry for the malformed post. I've added a google drop link where to find the three CMakeLists that I'm using in the project. I'm not very confident with CMake and I'm still learning,so it's very hard for me to find the error :(

Comment: No, not a *link* to the code, but the **code itself**. Copy-paste it into the question post, and format with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button. Read also [ask] help page.

Comment: hope it's fine now :)

Comment: Did you solve this?